# JSESSION ID changing after post request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application running in tomcat server and have a domain like `www.foo.com` which I have exposed a rest endpoint for a third party application running in a different domain like `www.acme.com`.

So I have enabled cross origin call from `www.acme.com` to `www.foo.com`, however something weird is happening. During the first post request everything is normal, however the succeeding request after two mins changes the JSESSION_ID of the user in the browser. I checked on my application and I didn't see any settings that may cause the issue so I'm thinking that there is a setting/configuration in the server level that might cause the issue.

Did I miss any configuration in the application that may cause this to happen?

Comment: REST and JSESSIONID is a contradiction. REST is stateless.

Comment: For some reason we need to expose a rest endpoint for the third party application to  access user details. However I can't figure out that it only works on the first two minutes, After that it seems that user session was invalidated and reset. The session cookie information was purged.